# Show that $n!^{n+1}$ divides $(n^2)!$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

My attempt so far is by induction. Let $f(n) = \frac{(n^2)!}{n!^{n+1}}$, I will try showing that $f(n)$ is a positive integer for all $n$.

We have $f(0) = \frac{0!}{0!^{n+1}} = 1$.

Now assume for induction, that $f(n) = k$ for some positive integer k.

Next, I'll examine $f(n+1) = \frac{((n+1)^2)!}{(n+1)!^{n+2}}$.

Note that $(n+1)!^{n+2} = [(n+1)(n)!]^{n+2} = (n+1)^{n+2}(n)!^{n+2} = (n+1)^{n+2}(n)!(n)!^{n+1}$.

And that $(n+1)!^2 = \frac{(n+1)^2!}{n^2!}n^2!$

So $f(n+1) = \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2!}{n^2!}n^2!}{(n+1)^{n+2}(n)!(n)!^{n+1}} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2!}{n^2!}}{(n+1)^{n+2}(n)!} \frac{(n^2)!}{n!^{n+1}} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2!}{n^2!}}{(n+1)^{n+2}(n)!}k$.

Additionally, I can show that $\frac{(n+1)^2!}{n^2!} = \prod_{i=0}^{2n}{(n+1)^2-i}$.

And this is where I don't how to proceed. Any tips? I'm willing to scrap all this and start from scratch as this feels like a dead end.

Comment: How about using the formula for the highest power of a prime $p$ that divides a factorial?  Then apply it for all primes.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but it might. 
Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\left((n+1)^2\right)!}{\left(n^2\right)!\cdot{n!}}={(n+1)^2 \choose n^2}\cdot{\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}}={(n+1)^2 \choose n^2}\cdot{{2n+1 \choose n}}\cdot{(n+1)!}$

Comment: [Related sequence](http://oeis.org/A057599).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial proof:

Arrange $n^2$ person in $n^2$ chairs in a row, we have $n^2!$ ways.

Alternatively, we can pick $n$ persons for the first $n$ chairs, then $n$ persons for chairs $n+1$ to $2n$, then $n$ persons for $2n + 1$ to $3n$, etc, then arrange each group of $n$ persons, we have $\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-kn \choose n}\right)(n!)^n$ ways

So $$n^2! = \left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-kn \choose n}\right)(n!)^n$$

Then we only need to prove $n!$ divides $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-kn \choose n}$.

Denote by $K$the number of ways of dividing $n^2$ persons into non-ordered $n$ groups, each of which contains $n$ persons , then actually we can note

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-kn \choose n} = Kn!$$

because $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-kn \choose n}$ is the way of dividing $n^2$ persons into ordered $n$ groups, each of which contains $n$ persons.

Now it's done. In summary, to arrange $n^2$ person in $n^2$ chairs in a row($n^2$! ways), we can divided them into non-ordered $n$ groups of equal size($K$ ways), make a permutation for those groups($n!$ ways), and then make permutations inside each group($(n!)^n$ ways). So we have $$(n^2)! = K (n!)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

> Show that $n!^{n+1}$ divides $(n^2)!$

More generally, we can prove that $n!\cdot (m!)^n$ divides $(mn)!$. [This is a special case where $m=n$.]

Credits to [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-that-mn-is-divisible-by-n-cdot-m-n/answer/Hood-Chatham).

$(mn)!/(n!\cdot (m!)^n)$ counts the number of ways of dividing $mn$ number of people into $n$ number of teams each of size $m$. I would encourage you to think why.

> 1. There are $(mn)!$ ways to arrange $mn$ people in an $n\times m$ grid. 
>  2. Each of these $n$ rows corresponds to a team we are seeking. 
>  3. There are $n!$ ways to rearrange these rows.  Mind that the ordering of the teams does not matter. This gives us a factor of $n!$. 
>  4. There are $m!$ ways to rearrange the members of each of the $n$ teams. Again, the ordering of members of a particular team does not matter. This gives us a factor of $(m!)^n$. 
>  5. Thus, we have $(mn)!/(n!\cdot (m!)^n)$ ways of selecting $n$ teams, each of size $m$.