# An odd combinatorics formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I ran into a formula during my TA session with an intro discrete course, that I am having a hard time proving.
$$
\displaystyle
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{{n^2 - in} \choose n} = \frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}
$$
Does anyone have an idea of how to prove this?

Comment: A combinatorical proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979886/show-that-nn1-divides-n2


A generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301558/why-r-divides-the-integer-fracrnnr-and-why-fracrnnr

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}{{n^2 - in} \choose n} \\&=& \color{blue}{\binom{n^2}{n} } &\color{red}{\binom{n^2-n}{n}} &\cdots \binom{n}{n} \\ &=& \color{blue}{\frac{(n^2)(n^2-1)\cdots (n^2-n+1)}{(n!)}} &\color{red}{\frac{(n^2-n)(n^2-n-1)\cdots (n^2-2n+1)}{(n!)}}& \cdots \frac{n!}{n!} \\.
\end{eqnarray*}